# How to create a window popup using nextjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js

Is there a way to create a popup like this image below.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open). The position and size are given in the optional [window features argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#position_and_size_features)

If you would like to use state from the parent window in the child window, you can use [react-new-window](https://github.com/rmariuzzo/react-new-window#readme).